# Simple counter-example of a Topological/Set Theory Statement

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

This is probably a simple question to answer, but I am reading through a Topology Textbook (Munkres) and cannot seem to understand why when considering a function $f: X \to Y$ between topological spaces, the following holds:

$f\left(f^{-1}(B)\right)$ is a subset of $B$

My question is, why is it not true that in fact, the stronger relation holds:

$f\left(f^{-1}(B)\right) = B$

Is there an elementary example that shows why it can be that the image of the pre-image of a set is not simply the set itself?  I believe somewhere in the book the result is written off as trivial, but I can't exactly remember.

Comment: Because $B$ may contain elements not in the image of $f$. Just take any non-surjective $f$ and $B=Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the zero function. Then $f^{-1}([-1, 1]) = \mathbb{R}$ and $f(f^{-1}([-1,1]))=\{0\} \subsetneq [-1, 1]$.

Comment: Thank you for your response, however I don't understand how it is possible to define the inverse function for the interval you gave.  In other words I was under the impression that you couldn't define an inverse function for the entire co-domain since the function you gave only maps to 0.

Comment: @Kade: The notation $f^{-1}$ has two different meanings. Here it is not a function with domain $\Bbb R$. It’s a relation: $\langle x,y\rangle\in f^{-1}$ iff $\langle y,x\rangle\in f$ iff $f(y)=x$. When $A$ is a subset of the codomain of $f$, by definition $f^{-1}[A]$ is the set of $x$ in the domain of $f$ such that $f(x)\in A$. Here $f^{-1}[A]=\{x\in\Bbb R:f(x)\in A\}$. I (and many others) use square brackets here, writing $f^{-1}[A]$ instead of $f^{-1}(A)$; this is to emphasize that we’re not evaluating a function $f^{-1}$ at a point in the range of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B$ be a subset of $Y$. Then $f\bigl(f^{-1}(B)\bigr)=B$ if and only if $B\subset f(X)$. So, take *any* set $B$ which is not a subset of the range of $f$.